# Will changing a MySQL user's password break existing connections?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, authentication

If I update a user's password or privileges in MySQL, how does this affect existing connections?  In particular, if I change the replication user password, will it break replication for connected slaves?

**Edit:** Assume I am using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after updating the information.

Answer (score 1):

According to [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)

[image]

Page 489 under the subheading says 'Statement Privilege Checking' says:

> Each time the server receives a statement from a client, it check's the client's privileges to see whether it is allowed to execute the statement.

Since MySQL grants are checked in memory, then one of two things must happen

## SCENARIO #1

If you ran standard GRANT commands to change the password, the password change is recording on disk via `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` automatically. (See Section 34.1.2 "The Grant Tables")

## SCENARIO #2

If you hacked the password in, as follows (shown in Section 35.5.1 Page 498):

```
SET @newpass = PASSWORD('whateverpasswordiwant');
UPDATE mysql.user SET PASSWORD = @newpass WHERE user='replication_user';
```

This stores the password on disk but does not push it into the in-memory copy of the MySQL Grants. As long as you don't run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` or restart mysqld, you have a chance to change it back. Newer versions of MySQL 5.5 may not be as forgiving.

SHORT ANSWER : For `SCENARIO #1`, Yes, for `SCENARIO #2`, more than likely.

Comment: "Checking the privileges" seems different that "checking the password".  So, I question the logic behind this answer, and hence, its conclusion.

Comment: Updated my question to clarify -- I'm interested in the normal case where I update the information correctly (using `GRANT` or `SET PASSWORD` followed by `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`), so scenario 2 is not really relevant.

Comment: doesnt change a thing .. the user IS already logged in. Check privileges doesnt cover the password check but the roles and rights for the user.